# Is it possible store without a database at android?

Tags: java, android, database, mobile, store

Is possible store a list within application, without necessarily having a database?
Otherwise, what would be the easiest way to store a simple list?

Comment: You can always store data by creating a file.What is the problem with that?

Comment: What's in the list? Strings? that would be easy just save the string in a file seperate by whatever you want. if its objects try serializing them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on the contents of the list you are working on. If your List is storing "Simple-Objects" only (like List of String  List of integer or other Objects with only a few members)  you can use SharedPrefenrences which are build in in Android. They need a key and a value. So if your List contains 5 Objects of - lets say Points to keep it simple - you can save them like

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("YourListName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
for(int i = 0; i < YOUR_LIST.count() ; i++){
    Point p = YOUR_LIST.get(i);
    editor.putInt("Element" + i + " X", p.x);
    editor.putInt("Element" + i + " Y", p.y);
}
editor.commit();
```

to recieve this again you could just say

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YourListName", MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String, ?> map = prefs.getAll();
```

Comment: Great, but what I supposed to do with the variable `p` ?

Comment: oops, sorry this was a typo. I assume that it was a List of Point, so i corrected it to p.x and p.y, because a Point Object has two members, int x, y. I corrected the Map from Map<String, ?> to <String, Point> to make it clear. So replace the Point and put your own Object inside.

Comment: Ah ok! In this case you will have to search the Point object for the key "Element2 X" for example, right? And, I think this `Map<String, Point> map = prefs.getAll()` doesnt work because `prefs.getAll()` returns a map<String, Integer> ... I suppose.

Comment: right you have to search for that. and you are right with your Int, because we put Ints inside. actually it returns map<String, ?>
You can put the YOUR_LIST.count() into a separate SharedPrefs to know how much you got if this was variable.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways for [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in Android:
Take a look to the developer zone, you have all the information you need there:

[Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
    Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

[Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) 
Store private data on the device memory.

[External Storage](http://External%20Storage)
    Store public data on the shared external storage.

[SQLite Databases](http://SQLite%20Databases)
    Store structured data in a private database.

[Network Connection](http://Network%20Connection)
    Store data on the web with your own network server.

Feel free to ask for any type of storage when you already find the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: I have a list of objects(not primitives) and would like to store them even if my application is killed. So, `SQLite Databases` is the best option, I suppose.

Comment: Exactly, I recommend a sqlite database. Also you should consider the option of using an ORM like http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple persistence alternatives to databases. To name a few (accessible with Java), you can

- Use simple files (with [serialisation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/), or other config format - in that case take a look at [commons configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/))
- Write XML content (with XML serialization - again ?!? - or other mechanisms, like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/), ...)
- Use any NoSQL storage (graph DB, document DB, and so on, ...)
- Use prevalence layer (like [space4j](http://www.space4j.org/))
- Use transactionnal data store (like [JDBM](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/))

To name only a few of the many storage abilities from Java

Comment: Space4J also offers indexation, with 4 different types of indexes. Take a look: http://forum.space4j.org/posts/list/5.page

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways, look at the doc
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Java allows you to use serialization of objects with easy API. [Here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) there is a technical article from java web page.

Comment: @mathiasnj and Cinquo. It seems [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). Is it the same thing?

Comment: It looks like Internal Storage allows to write to an application private area and probably this is what you may need if just your application need it. When I refer to serialization I mean having a method able to map (and write) your object with a specific format, into another format in a file (de-serializing would just be the opposite operation). The format can be whatever fits to you, in this case if it is a list of element, you can put one element per file line. You could also evaluate something like pickleing (cPickle library).