# Android data storage and retrieving

Tags: android, database, store

I developed an android application in which a users provides 6 pieces of information in 6 separate text boxes (information such as first name, last name, middle name, mobile number email id etc)

When the user presses a `Save` button, I need to store this information and be able to recall this information when the `Recall` button is pressed.

What is the next step to accomplish this

My code so far is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


        final DatePicker date = (DatePicker) findViewById (R.id.datePicker1);
        final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView88);
        final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView89);
        final TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView90);
        final TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView91);
        final TextView tv5 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView92);
        final TextView tv6 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView93);
        final TextView tv7 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView94);


        date.init(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDayOfMonth(),new OnDateChangedListener()
        {


        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker  arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



         String date=Integer.toString(arg3);
         String month=Integer.toString(arg2);
         String year=Integer.toString(arg1);

         tv1.setText(date+ month+1 +year);
         tv2.setText(month+1 + date);
         tv3.setText(year);
         tv4.setText(month+1);
         tv5.setText(date);
         tv6.setText(date + year);

        }   

    });}


    public void sum(View v)        
    {
        long sum1=0;
        long sum2=0;
        long sum3=0;
        long sum4=0;
        long sum5=0;
        long sum6=0;
        long sum7=0;
        long sum8=0;
        long sum=0;
        long sum11=0;
        long sum12=0;
        long sum13=0;
        long sum14=0;
        long sum100=0;




        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
        EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText4);
        EditText et5 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText5);
        EditText et6 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText6);


        final DatePicker date = (DatePicker) findViewById (R.id.datePicker1);
        final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView88);
        final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView89);
        final TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView90);
        final TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView91);
        final TextView tv5 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView92);
        final TextView tv6 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView93);
        final TextView tv7 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView94);







        sum1=getSum(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString() + et4.getText().toString());
        sum2=getSum1(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString() + et4.getText().toString());
        sum3=getSum2(tv1.getText().toString());
        /*sum4=getSum3(tv2.getText().toString());*/
        sum5=getSum4(tv3.getText().toString());
        sum6=getSum5(tv4.getText().toString());
        sum8=getSum7(tv5.getText().toString());


        String yearf = tv3.getText().toString();
        int yearb = Integer.valueOf(yearf);

        int val = 2013 - yearb;
        long val1 = sum3;
        /*int val2 = Integer.valueOf(val1);*/
        long val3 = 36 - val1;
        int val4 = 9;
        long val5 = val3 + val4;
        long val6 = val5 + val4;
        long val7 = val6 + 50;


        sum = getSum3(tv2.getText().toString()) + getSum8(tv6.getText().toString());
        sum100 = getSum4(tv3.getText().toString()) + getSum5(tv4.getText().toString());



        if (val <= val3)
        {
            sum4=getSum3(tv2.getText().toString());
        }

        else if ((val <= val5) && (val > val3))
        {
            sum4=getSum8(tv6.getText().toString());
        }

        else if ((val<=val6) && (val > val5) && (val > val3))
        {
            /*sum = getSum3(tv2.getText().toString()) + getSum8(tv6.getText().toString());*/
             sum4=getSum9(Integer.toString((int) sum));


        }
        else 
        {
             sum4=getSum9(Integer.toString((int) sum100));
        }






        if (val <= val3)
        {



        if (sum8>sum6)
        {
            sum7 = (sum8 - sum6);
        }
        else 
        {
            sum7 = (sum6 - sum8);
        }

        }

        else if ((val <= val5) && (val > val3))
        {
            if(sum5>sum8)
            {
                sum7=(sum5 - sum8);
            }
            else
            {
                sum7 = (sum8 - sum5);
            }
        }


        else if ((val<=val6) && (val > val5) && (val > val3))
        {
            sum11 = (sum5 - sum8);
            sum12 = (sum8 - sum5);
            sum13 = (sum6 - sum8);
            sum14 = (sum8 - sum6);

            if ((sum11 > sum12) && (sum13 > sum14))
            {
                if (sum11 > sum13)
                {
                    sum7 = sum11 - sum13;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = sum13 - sum11;
                }
            }
            else if ((sum12 > sum11) && (sum13 > sum14))
            {
                if (sum12 > sum13)
                {
                    sum7 = sum12 - sum13;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = sum13 - sum12;
                }
            }
            else if ((sum11 > sum12) && (sum14 > sum13))
            {
                if (sum11 > sum14)
                {
                    sum7 = sum11 - sum14;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = sum14 - sum11;
                }
            }
            else if ((sum12 > sum11) && (sum14 > sum13))
            {
                if (sum12 > sum14)
                {
                    sum7 = sum12 - sum14;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = sum14 - sum12;
                }
            }

        }
            else 
            {

                if (sum5>sum6)
                {
                    sum7 = (sum5 - sum6);
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum7 = (sum6 - sum5);
                }

                }










        String edtxt1 = et1.getText().toString();
        String edtxt4 = et4.getText().toString();
        String edtxt5 = et5.getText().toString();
        String edtxt6 = et6.getText().toString();

        if(edtxt1.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First Name should not be left blank, Please enter your First Name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if(edtxt4.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Last Name should not be left blank, Please enter your Last Name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(edtxt5.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Mobile Number should not be left blank, Please enter your Mobile Number ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(edtxt6.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"E-Mail id should not be left blank, Please enter your E-Mail id ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else{

        Intent i = new Intent(this, result.class);
        i.putExtra("name", sum1 + "");
        i.putExtra("name1", sum2 + "");
        i.putExtra("name2", sum3 + "");
        i.putExtra("name3", sum4 + "");
        i.putExtra("name4", sum7 + "");



        startActivity(i);


        }


public long getSum(String text) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long sum1 = 0;
        char[] name = new char[text.length()];
        name = text.toCharArray();


        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
        {
            sum1 += value( name[i] );

        }
        while (sum1>9)
        {
            sum1 = findDigitSum(sum1);
        }

        return sum1;
    }



    public long getSum1(String text) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long sum2 = 0;
        char[] name1 = new char[text.length()];
        name1 = text.toCharArray();


        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
        {
            sum2 += value1( name1[i] );

        }
        while (sum2>9)
        {
            sum2 = findDigitSum(sum2);
        }

        return sum2;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572988/is-it-possible-store-without-a-database-at-android?rq=1  It both gives a clean answer for storing simple structures like yours and the next answer is listing all possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDBI", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE1 ();");
```

You can create database using this code

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('"+fname"');

And values can be inserted to this database using this code.

A tablelayout can be created and the saved details can be displayed in this tablelayout. Give  clickable option and clicking all the details can be transferred using intents to the previous activity.